# Using a 700x23 tire on my wheel (which currently accomodates 700x25)

Tags: tire, wheels

I have Mavic Reflex 622 x 13 (700c) wheels which currently hold 25mm tires. Can I use 23mm tires on them?

Comment: Starting to get a little narrow, but you could probably go down to about an 18mm tire on that rim before you had problems.  If the 25s are OK then 2mm isn't enough to make things go sour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like it, see 
[Sheldon Brown (as usual)](http://sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html#width).  There's very little difference between 23 and 25 anyway.

Comment: Depends on the application. There is a very large difference aerodynamically depending on the rim shape and depth that the tire is paired with. Admittedly this is primarily a time trial consideration, but tire/rim selection can have dramatic impacts on Cda.

Comment: True of course - but I was answering in terms of fit.

Answer (score 2):

I use 23mm and 21mm tyres on my Mavic Reflex rims. It's fine.